# can we write custom marker interfaces

Tags: java

I want to write my own marker interfaces like `java.io.Serializable` or `Cloneable` which can be understandable to JVM. Please suggest me the implementation procedure.

For example I implemented a interface called `NotInheritable` and all the classes implementing this interface has to avoid inheritance.

Comment: What do you mean by `understandable to JVM` ?

Comment: No, but the JVM supports http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/final.html to mark classes as "not inheritable".

Comment: Answer is NO, If you want to create any marker "Interface of significance" then no you cant create. But if you want to create marker interface just to check if class object is object of that marker interface then YES you can. To create Marker interface "Understandable to JVM" jvm need to be customized and i am not sure if it can be done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public interface MyMarkerInterface {}

public class MyMarkedClass implements MyMarkerInterface {}
```

Then you can for example have method taking only `MyMarkerInterface` instance:

```
public myMethod(MyMarkerInterface x) {}
```

or check with `instanceof` at runtime.

Answer (score 2):

Yes We can write our own marker exception.... see following example....

```
interface Marker{   
}

class MyException extends Exception {   

    public MyException(String s){
        super(s);
    }
}

class A implements Marker {

   void m1() throws MyException{        
     if((this instanceof Marker)){
         System.out.println("successfull");
     }
     else {
         throw new MyException("Unsuccessful  class must implement interface Marker ");
     }      
}   
}

/* Class B has not implemented Maker interface .
 * will not work & print unsuccessful Must implement interface Marker
*/
class B extends A  {    


}

// Class C has not implemented Maker interface . Will work & print successful

public class C  extends A implements Marker   
 { // if this class will not implement Marker, throw exception
     public static void main(String[] args)  {
     C a= new C();
     B b = new B();

     try {
        a.m1(); // Calling m1() and will print
        b.m1();
     } catch (MyException e) {

        System.out.println(e);
    }

}
}
```

[image: OUTOPUT]

Comment: The example seems entirely pointless. Why wouldn't you just have class Aa implement the marker interface?

Answer (score 1):

suppose myMethod should be called only if marker MyInterface should be marked there.

```
interface MyInterface{}

class MyException extends RuntimeException{

    public MyException(){}
    public MyException(String message){
        super(message);
    }
}

class MyClass implements MyInterface{
    public void myMethod(){
        if(!(this instanceOf MyInterface)){
            throw new MyException();
        }else{
            // DO YOUR WORK
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write your own Marker interface ,JVM do not know anything about it.

You have to provide functionality by using `instanceof`. [check this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2146640/is-this-possible-to-write-a-marker-interface)

Answer (score -3):

A marker interface is an empty interface. This mean you just need to create a interface and do not create any method in it. Better explanation you will find [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marker_interface_pattern).

This approach can be replaced with [Annotations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_annotation) that have similar functionality over types. [more](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/annotations.html)

Comment: maker still have there own importance .