# Serialization error when using out.writeObject(object)

Tags: java, serialization, marker-interfaces

I was studying the behavior of Marker Interfaces,i made my own marker interface using the below link,

[Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10551699/can-we-write-custom-marker-interfaces)

Then i am comparing the functionality of Serializable interface.

Now i have class Employee which do not extend serializable interface

```
public class Employee {

public String name;
public String address;
public int number;
 }
```

Then i have another class SerializeDemo which tries to serialize the object

```
public class SerializeDemo {

    public static void main(String [] args)
       {
          Employee e = new Employee();
          e.name = "AAAA";
          e.address = "BBB, India";
          e.number = 101;

          try
          {
             FileOutputStream fileOut =  new FileOutputStream("employee.ser");
             ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(fileOut);
             out.writeObject(e); //Error on this line( ERRORLINE)
             out.close();
             fileOut.close();
             System.out.printf("Serialized data is saved in /tmp/employee.ser");
          }catch(IOException i)
          {
              i.printStackTrace();
          }
       }
}



Error : java.io.NotSerializableException: com.serializable.Employee
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(Unknown Source)......
```

Now when i remove the line ERRORLINE then it compiles and make a new file but have no object. 
I just wanted to know how out.writeObject(e); leads to error, 
does ObjectOutputStream implements Serializable interface or it extends to some other class which implements Serializable interface.

How out.writeObject(e); internally check that it is serializable or not??

Any help will be highly appreciated !!

Answer (score 1):

Objects you want to serialize has to be marked Serializable.

Comment: I think you have not understood question , please read it carefully, i know that we need to mark them Serializable

Comment: @MandeepSingh then why are you surprised to get that exception, since Employee does NOT implement Serializable?

Comment: I wanted to know that why it gave exception internally, in hierarchy which class implements Serializable and ObjectOutputStream extends which class which let him know this behaviour

Comment: ObjectOutputStream simply does something like `if (!(object instanceof Serializable)) throw new NotSerializableException`. Your Employee object does not implement Serializable, so the exception is thrown. ObjectOutputStream itself doesn't need to implement or extend anything to be able to do that.

Comment: No, i didnt understand what your problem is

Comment: But @JBNizet gave the answer i needed, please remove downvote and give it  the answer, so that i can mark him right answer